# Need to find average, sum, minimum, and maximum of the numbers I generated in printf

Tags: java, printf

I need to find the average, sum, minimum, and maximum of the random numbers I generate that appear on my printf method. The top part is all done, but I just need to print out the results to those 4 questions at the bottom.

> /****************************************************************************
>
> - This program will generate a series of random numbers, and produce a table
>     *containing calculations. 
>     ****************************************************************************/

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class GoslinMelissaUnit5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        final String HEADING_FMT_STR = "%5s%9s%13.8s%11s%11s%11s \n";   // headers
        final String DATA_FMT_STR = "%5d%7d%13.2f%14.2f%11.2f%11.2f \n";    // data received 

        String maxRandomNumStr;  // max random #
        int maxRandomNumInt;     // max random number after converted
        String roundsStr;        // rounds after converted
        int roundsInt;           // number of rounds

        int randomNumber;        // random number
        double fraction;        // fraction of random #
        double cubed;           // random number cubed
        double sqrt;            // square root of random #
        double log;             // log of random #



        System.out.print("Enter a maximum random number. (Example: 1-50) ");
        maxRandomNumStr = stdIn.next();

        maxRandomNumInt = Integer.parseInt(maxRandomNumStr);   // wrapper class convert string to integer 

        System.out.print("Enter the number of rounds (Example: 1-20) ");
        roundsStr = stdIn.next();

        roundsInt = Integer.parseInt(roundsStr);   // wrapper class convert string to integer

        System.out.printf("\n" + HEADING_FMT_STR,
                "Round", "Rand #", "Fraction", "x^3", "Sqrt", "Log");    // headers


        for (int rounds = 1; rounds <= roundsInt; rounds++)
        {

        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * maxRandomNumInt + 1);
        fraction = maxRandomNumInt / randomNumber;
        cubed = randomNumber * randomNumber * randomNumber;
        sqrt = (Math.sqrt(randomNumber));
        log = (Math.log(randomNumber));

        System.out.printf("\n" + DATA_FMT_STR,                          // data
                rounds, randomNumber, fraction, cubed, sqrt, log);

        } // end for loop


        System.out.println("The minimum generated number is: ");
        System.out.println("The maximum generated number is: ");
        System.out.println("The total of generated numbers is: ");
        System.out.println("The average of generated numbers is: ");

    }  // end main

}    // end class GoslinMelissaUnit5
```

Comment: What is the specific question being asked here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I need to do _X_" is not a question.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to java. So it will out put 10 random numbers from 1-40, and they will appear in my printf method. So for example..... 15,20,40,30,9,6,7,32,36,24. So from those numbers I need to find the min which is 6 for this example. The max is 40. The sum would be adding all these numbers up, and then find the average of all these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write about it, for example:

double minNumber = 0.0;

System.out.println("The minimum generated number is: "+minNumber);

And you need to do it for all varivables

Comment: Yeah, I figured that and I understand that. I'm just confused on how to get the values that are input from the user instead of assigning double minNumber = 0.0

Comment: When user _input number you can convert it in double:
for example:
double d = Double.parseDouble(_input);